# Status bar has black background behind it - even when not visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, statusbar

I have the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO];
```

Anything I put behind the status bar, including a background color, can't be seen however. And when i do this, it just leaves a black background behind where it was:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the status bar to hidden in the application's info.plist? Does that make a difference?